# Run gnome-terminal from tty

Tags: linux, tty, gnome-terminal

How can I run `gnome-terminal` from `tty1`?

I tried setting `$DISPLAY` variable to `:0`, but still nothing and `gnome-terminal` doesn't appear in the X window system.

However, `xterm` and `firefox`, work fine from tty1.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by tty1?

Did you run xstart when you were on tty1 and got a GUI where you expect everything to run?

It is possible that gnome-terminal expect some familiar desktop environment but crash due to lack of one. It is possible that you will need to specify the Xorg display with `--display=DISPLAY` option even if there is only one display.

Run `gnome-terminal --help-all` and read the output for more info.

Sorry for asking you questions in answer section but I apparently don't have enough reputation to add a comment.